# Hotkey for moving messages from inbox to archive in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I'd like to configure a hotkey, in **MS Outlook**, which does the following to the highlighted/selected **messages**:

- Mark as read (by default it's **[crtl]+Q**)
- Move to an "archive" folder (archive meaning a folder other than the default inbox)

This should happen whenever I press **[crtl]+M** (assuming it is not already reserved), on any amount of messages I select.

I currently use **Outlook 2007**.

Comment: I have the macro, but I need the hotkey setup.

Comment: One workaround is Ctrl+A,Q,Shift+V. In other words, hold Ctrl key, press A (Select All), then Q (Mark As Read), then press Shift+V (Move to Folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be difficult to assign a **Hotkey** to a Macro in Outlook, but you can add the Macro as a **button** in the toolbars.